# select appropriate dataframe based on user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the below data frames loaded :

1. df_1000-2000
2. df_3000-4000
3. df_5000-6000
4. df_7000-8000

Now I get a user input value as 1000-2000. Based on the user input value I need to work on respective data frame.
In this case, I need to work on : df_1000-2000

How to select the data frame dynamically based on user input and start working on it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use a dictionary

You should restructure how you store and access your dataframes. First define a dictionary:

```
dfs = {'1000-2000': df_1000-2000, '3000-4000': df_3000-4000, etc.}
```

Then taking a user input and using it to query your dictionary is straightforward:

```
value = input('Input the range you require, e.g. 1000-2000:')
res = dfs[value]
```